# Understanding Kafka Consumer API for Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to understand the Kafka Receiving API. I have included a sample code that works.

1. Why does Kafka consumerStreamMap.get(topic) for a single topic have a list of KafkaStream<> receivers?
2. The current process seems to iterate through the KafkaStream<> List, and then iterate through messages. But KafkaReceiver is supposed to run for ever, so I would expect that the inner while to loop forever. This makes the List> redundant.
3. A few examples also use consumerStreamMap.get(topic).get(0). Is this the right way to write a producer then?

   ```
       Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       // Define single thread for topic
       topicMap.put(topicName, new Integer(1));
       Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreamsMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicMap);
       List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streamList = consumerStreamsMap.get(topic);

       for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streamList) 
       {
          ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIte = stream.iterator();
          while (consumerIte.hasNext()) 
          {
             counter++;
             String message = new String(consumerIte.next().message());
             String id = topic.hashCode() + "-" + date.getTime() + "-" + counter;
             System.out.println(message);
           }
         }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find answers in the kafka wiki:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

1. consumerStreamMap is a map of (topic, list of  KafkaStream) pairs. Number of streams depends on the following row in your code:

   ```
   topicMap.put(topicName, numberOfStreams);
   ```

> if you provide more threads than there are partitions on the topic,
>   some threads will never see a message. 
>   if you have more partitions than
>   you have threads, some threads will receive data from multiple
>   partitions.
>   if you have multiple partitions per thread there is NO
>   guarantee about the order you receive messages, other than that within
>   the partition the offsets will be sequential. 
>   For example, you may
>   receive 5 messages from partition 10 and 6 from partition 11, then 5
>   more from partition 10 followed by 5 more from partition 10 even if
>   partition 11 has data available. 
>   adding more processes/threads will
>   cause Kafka to re-balance, possibly changing the assignment of a
>   Partition to a Thread.

2. you need to iterate each stream in its own thread.

   ```
   public void run(int a_numThreads) {
       Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
       Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
       List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

       // now launch all the threads
       //
       executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(a_numThreads);

       // now create an object to consume the messages
       //
       int threadNumber = 0;
       for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
           executor.submit(new ConsumerTest(stream, threadNumber));
           threadNumber++;
       }
   }

   public class ConsumerTest implements Runnable {
       private KafkaStream m_stream;
       private int m_threadNumber;

       public ConsumerTest(KafkaStream a_stream, int a_threadNumber) {
           m_threadNumber = a_threadNumber;
           m_stream = a_stream;
       }

       public void run() {
           ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
           while (it.hasNext())
               System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new      String(it.next().message()));
           System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
       }
   }
   ```
3. consumerStreamMap.get(topic).get(0) is correct only if you have 1 topic and 1 stream

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) Just a clarification on Point 3. basically you meant if I have 1 stream per topic, I can still have multiple topics and only one stream per topic. I am trying to implement a lockstep mechanism for multiple topics, where I take input from two topics one after the other. So just confirming this.